# Не работает сортировка sql

Tags: sql

Имеется такая таблица:
[image: таблица]

Пишу запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM pc ORDER BY code
```

Однако сортировка не работает, вывод остается в точности такой же как и без order by, когда я ожидаю вывод по возрастанию по столбцу code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `code` у вас имеет строковый тип и все записи сортируются по строковому значению. Вам нужно либо сделать тип числовым, либо сделать преобразование при сортировке

```
ORDER BY CAST(code AS INTEGER)
```

Comment: Я сначала тоже так же подумал, однако и так не работает, возможно это какой-то баг. Задачи делаются на сайте http://www.sql-ex.ru это в частности 83-я.

Comment: Покажите DDL таблицы

Comment: http://www.sql-ex.ru/download/computer_dml_script.sql

Comment: Все работает http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8051c/1

Comment: А поле `code` случаем не `string`? Выглядит так, как будто форматируются строковые значения. И зачем, если не секрет, использовать `string` для поля где не предполагается использование значений с ведущими нулями?

Comment: Да, видимо все-таки баг, напишу в поддержку сайта.

Comment: @Rootware вы мой ответ читали?

Comment: @Reject а попробуйте `ORDER BY code DESC`. Что-то изменится?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov извиняюсь. Не дочитал до конца, увидев ваш костыль.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov нет

Comment: Нужно просто читать FAQ: http://www.sql-ex.ru/faq.php#f4